# Struggling to disprove this flow network question

Tags: data-structures, network-flow

> Consider a flow network $G$. Let $(S, T)$ be a min-cut of $G$. Let
> $(u, v)$ be an edge that crosses the cut from $S$ to $T$. Claim:
> increasing the capacity of $(u, v)$ causes the value of the maximum
> flow in $G$ to increase.

I'm 99% sure this is false, but I'm struggling to disprove it. Can anyone give me some tips to find a counter-example?

I thought of making a graph with a cut and having two edges run through this cut such that one is the minimum and one is greater; increasing the greater one won't change the max-flow by the min-cut theorem.

Comment: We require you to credit the original source of all copied material.  See https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing

Comment: Don't use images as main content of your post. This makes your question impossible to search and inaccessible to the visually impaired; [we don't like that](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/752/should-we-do-anything-about-questions-that-are-just-a-scan-of-a-problem-in-their). Please transcribe text and mathematics.  You can [use LaTeX](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands).

Comment: I suggest you spend some more time working on this on your own, and trying a few examples.  Do you have an example of a graph of the form mentioned in the last paragraph?   I suggest drawing one, with concrete capacities on all edges.  Does the max flow change, when you change the edge capacity?  Does the min cut change?  You should be able to try that for yourself.

Comment: @D.W. Just transcribed it; sorry about that!

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a homework question, I'll provide a hint.

Instead of having two edges in the cut, why not try with only one? What if your graph is only one long path?